# Expose Excel InlineShapes to edit

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to automatize filling in a third party form from an Excel Workbook VBA module. They sadly have gone with a Word document with an in-line Excel workbook embedded, which contains cells as named ranges that I want to edit.

How do I assign the InlineShapes object to an Excel.workbook object so that I can expose it to Excel methods and properties?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
Sub test()
        Dim wdApp As Word.Application
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("word.application")
        wdApp.Visible = true ' for testing
        Dim wdAppendixB As Word.Document
        Set wdAppendixB = wdApp.Documents.Add(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Templates\form_template.dotx")
        Dim wbAppB As Excel.Workbook
        wdAppendixB.InlineShapes.Item(1).OLEFormat.Edit
        Set wbAppB = wdAppendixB.InlineShapes.Item(1).OLEFormat.Object
        wbAppB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("date1").Value = "2019-06-02"
Exit Sub
```

As soon as the script opens the OLE object for editing, the script stops with no errors. Closing the OLE object for editing does not resume the script.

If I omit editing the object and just set the workbook object to the OLEFormat.Object it errors out with Run-time error '430' "Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface".

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Activate`, instead of `Edit` (or `DoVerb` with an appropriate `wdOleVerb` constant).

Note that this will leave the object in an activated state. There's no elegant way to emulate the user clicking outside the object to de-select it. The workarounds are to either open the object in its own window (instead of in-place) and close that file window OR to try to activate the object as a specific, non-existant class. Since this will trigger an error, this has to be wrapped in `On Error Resume Next'  and 'On Error GoTo 0'.

```
Sub test()
        Dim wdApp As Word.Application
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("word.application")
        wdApp.Visible = True ' for testing
        Dim wdAppendixB As Word.Document
        Set wdAppendixB = wdApp.Documents.Add(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Templates\form_template.dotx")
        Dim wbAppB As Excel.Workbook
        Dim of As Word.OLEFormat
        Set of = wdAppendixB.InlineShapes.Item(1).OLEFormat
        of.Activate '.Edit
        Set wbAppB = of.Object
        wbAppB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = "2019-06-02"
        On Error Resume Next
        of.ActivateAs "This.Class.NotExist"
        On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this. Works though I cannot understand why without setting the OLEFormat object, when activating the object the script stops. With setting "of" object the script does not stop when activating. Not understanding why the difference. In any case much appreciated.

Comment: @nbayly Not sure what you're saying... `wdAppendixB.InlineShapes.Item(1).OLEFormat.Activate` should work and I originally had that. Until I wanted to include the `ActivateAs`. Note the small change I just made: `of` can be used again to get the `Object`, as well, rather than writing out the entire "path". Or did you try `OLEFormat.Object.activate`? That would not work...

Comment: I did do `OLEFormat.Activate` but when running this command or the `.Edit` the script stops when opening the instance of Excel except when dim'ing and setting the  `Word.OLEFormat` object `of`. If  you omit this step the script opens up the inline shape but then does nothing further (just exits run mode) including setting the values in the object. Just curious why this is.

Comment: @nbayly I can only guess that the code may lose the connection to the `InlineShape` object since, once it's been activated, Word may no longer "see" it as an `InlineShape` - it may be in some kind of "limbo" state.